# Why is the song E.P.M. by Dragonforce only on the Japanese release?

Tags: metal

The album Ultra Beatdown by the power metal band Dragonforce contains 11 total songs. 8 of those are on the main album, 2 are bonuses for the special edition and one of them, E.P.M., is only on the Japanese edition of the album. What possible reason could there be for doing such a thing?

Answer (score -1):

Many bands adds bonus/special song on Japanese Edition.   Because almost albums firstly released on Japan. Especially Metal albums.